# Adobe Reader cannot read fonts from my project?

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, itext, adobe

I am generating the PDF using `iTextPdf version 5` and am using `Calibri font` inside that PDF. I have loaded that font from the `src/resource/fonts` folder as I am working with Boot. All is working fine as I can view that PDF in my project and download also except that when I am trying to open the PDF using Adobe Reader, than the page is showing something like that-

[image: Image in Adobe]

I have opened that PDF using Google Chrome, WPS office and other PDF Reader and that PDF is working perfectly fine but I can't seem to understand what is wrong when I am trying to view the PDF using Adobe. I have also attached the screenshot of PDF in WPS office below -

[image: PDF in WPS Office]

Here is the code that I have loaded the font in my PDF -

```
static URL calibriFont = UserProfileController.class.getResource("/static/fonts/Calibri Regular.ttf");
static Font namefont = FontFactory.getFont(calibriFont.toString(), 20, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(139, 0, 0));
FontFactory.register(calibriFont.toString());
```

Here is the PDF File link shared below -
[Sample PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13JTjrmyo9zK55J3CrzfWAZyRito36RwE)

Comment: Please share the example PDF in question which illustrates the issue.

Comment: @mkl I have attahced the pdf in the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

Additional data was added to the PDF after initial generation, introducing a cross reference error. Take the first 1019493 bytes of the file to get the original working file.

My first guess would be another program postprocessing the PDF incorrectly but as it turned out the iText objects were closed incorrectly resulting in that error.

#### In detail

The final version of the PDF you shared is not generated by iText, at least not by correct iText usage.

The file has a size of 1021972 bytes. The initial 1019493 bytes constitute a valid PDF.

The extra 2479 bytes extend the PDF providing some updated old object, some new objects, and a full cross reference table. And in this cross reference table the offset entry for the first new object 33 is incorrect, it should be 0001019493 (the first byte added after the original contents, i.e. the start of the first new object) but it is 0001018667 (the start of the cross reference table of the original PDF).

Thus, a PDF processor will incorrectly find the original cross references when looking for the new object 33.

As the object 33 happens to contain the **FontDescriptor** of the font Calibri in the updated object 1, an attempt to parse this font fails. This font is referenced from all document pages.

As a results, Adobe Reader stops drawing each page as soon as it comes across an instruction using that font.

Some other PDF viewers repair that error under the hood and, therefore, show you what you want to see.

#### The actual cause

In a comment you write

> The error was coming due to PdfWriter instance object was closed before document.

Indeed, you are not expected to close the `PdfWriter` at all, and in particular not before the `Document`.

When requesting a `PdfWriter` using `PdfWriter.getInstance` for a `Document`, a `PdfDocument` instance is created and registered as listener of the `Document`; then a `PdfWriter` is created and registered as listener of the `PdfDocument`.

To finalize the PDF generation you are expected to close the `Document`. This will call its listeners' respective `close` methods, i.e. `PdfDocument.close`, which will finish some last objects, write them, and then call its own listener's `close` method, i.e. `PdfWriter.close`, which will write the cross references.

In your code you first explicitly called `PdfWriter.close` (which wrote the first cross reference table) and then `Document.close` (which caused `PdfDocument` to write some objects and then trigger `PdfWriter.close` again to write the second cross references). This incorrect sequence also resulted in an incorrect cross reference offset.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I solve this issue, as I am stuck in this from few days and unable to do.

Comment: I don't know which other code manipulates your pdf (and so introduces the error). I'd propose removing that code.

Comment: The error was coming due to PdfWriter instance object was closed before document.

Comment: Ah, ok. So no other program, merely wrong usage. I'll update the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of my problem as what I was doing that, I have closed `PdfWriter` instance before the document. When I closed that instance after the document, it was working fine.

Comment: Please don't close the `PdfWriter` instance at all. As I've explained in my answer, the intended flow is that you close the `Document` which closes the internal `PdfDocument` which in turn closes the `PdfWriter`. If that flow succeeds, the `PdfWriter` is properly closed, and if it fails you should not expect a call of `PdfWriter.close` to improve anything.